# Changing the value of an integer inside a class , which is inside an arraylist?

Tags: java, processing

Hey I am working on some code and want to change the value of a integer stored an arraylist of class's, throughout my code I have been accessing different instances of the classes without issue using

```
arrayListName.get(index).variableName
```

and have not attempted to set them with

```
arrayListName.set(index).variableName = X;
```

but set seems to want parameters for changing a arraylist holding primitive data and not classes etc

This is my Code

```
    //ARRAYLIST DECLARATION
ArrayList<Ship> ship_arraylist = new ArrayList<Ship>();

void setup() {
  //ARRAYLIST INITIALIZE
  ship_arraylist = new ArrayList<Ship>();
  //LOAD DATA 
  loadData();
}//end Setup()

void loadData() {
  String[] lines = loadStrings("Data.csv"); // files must be in the data folder

  for (int i = 0; i<lines.length; i++) {
    ship_arraylist.add(new Ship(lines[i]));
  }// end for loop
}// end loadData

class Ship {
  int Alive=0;//1=Alive 0=Dead

  Ship(String line) {
    String[] parts = line.split(",");
    Alive = int(parts[1]);
  }
}
```

And then I have a mouseClicked function so that if a ship is clicked Alive is set to 0 , Probably should be using boolean for this but its just a big work in progress atm , I have tried the .setVariableName() before and it was giving a

```
"setVariableName(int)" does not exist
```

Really appreciate the help!!

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: What do you think `arrayListName.set(index)` does?

Answer (score 1):

well, if your `ArrayList` contains objects you can do this (assuming `variableName` is `public`):

```
arrayListName.get(index).variableName=x;
```

Your `ArrayList` only deals with the objects it contains, and changing a property value of a contained object is not setting a value in the array list, but on the contained object.

the `set` method is only used for setting the item at specified index in the list, in your case, to replace the `Ship` with another one.

```
arrayListName.set(index, new Ship());
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a class like this:

```
class MyClass{
   int x = 0;
}
```

You can create an instance of `MyClass` like this:

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
```

And you can set the `x` variable inside that instance like this:

```
mc.x = 42;
```

Similarly, we can create an `ArrayList` and add an instance of `MyClass` to it:

```
ArrayList<MyClass> mcList = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
mcList.add(new MyClass());
```

Now, to set the `x` variable of an instance of `MyClass` at a particular index in the `ArrayList`, you could think of it as two steps:

```
MyClass mc = mcList.get(0); //get the MyClass instance
mc.x = 42; //set the x variable
```

You can shorten this into a single line:

```
mcList.get(0).x = 42;
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you have objects inside an Arraylist, so you need to get the object in the Arraylist, then set its variables

```
arrayListName.get(index).setX(X);
```